# Proper Nested Search using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, listjs

I am using [list.js](http://www.listjs.com/) to search, sort and filter my menu items. I am having a problem using search function upon nested `<ul>`'s and couldn't avoid it.

The problem is when I search for a text in sub `<ul>` element, it returns the whole `<li>`'s in the sub `<ul>`.

Is there anything I am missing?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ukgqmsp/

Here is a sample code;

```js
  var options = {
      valueNames: ['demo-class']
  };
  var userList = new List('test', options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.2.0/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="3">3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="4">4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="5">5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="6">6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
      <a class="demo-class" href="#" title="7">7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam and @David stated, it was a library issue.

If someone is using or wants to use this library with nested functionality, it's avaliable under project's GitHub page.

[Github - List.js with nested functionality](https://github.com/bilalfastian/list.js/tree/feature/nested-search/dist)

An example usage;

```js
$(function() {
  var options = {
    valueNames: ['searchable'],
    item: '<li><a class="searchable" href="#"></a></li>',
    nestedSearch: true
  };
  var userList = new List('users', options);
})
```

```html
<div class="service-list">
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd>
      <div id="panel1" class="content">
        <ul class="list first-level">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="searchable link-first-level">Card Services Summary</a>
            <ul class="list">
              <li>
                <a class="searchable" href="#">Permanent Access Card</a>
                <ul class="list last-level">
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for new</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for replacement</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Cancel current</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="searchable" href="#">Permanent Identity Card</a>
                <ul class="list last-level">
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for new</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for replacement</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Cancel current</a></li>
                </ul>
              <li>
                <a class="searchable" href="#">Temporary Access Card</a>
                <ul class="list last-level">
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for new</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for replacement</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Cancel current</a></li>
                </ul>
              <li>
                <a class="searchable" href="#">Free Zone Card</a>
                <ul class="list last-level">
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for new</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for duplicate</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Apply for replacement</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Amend current</a></li>
                  <li><a class="searchable" href="#">Cancel current</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bilalfastian/list.js/feature/nested-search/dist/list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works great on existing HTML, how would you do it if the HTML was dynamic. I have tried many combinations but nothing seems to work....

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it would appear that searching nested lists is not currently supported in list.js (see [the Github issue](https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/59) ).

You could, however, create a custom solution by giving your nested list another class, creating a separate List.js & recursively searching?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Doesn't look like this sort of functionality has been implemented yet, nor does the author have any plans to add it.

Why not make your own raw jQuery solution?

```
$('.search-box').on('keyup', function(){

var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.list li').each(function(){

        if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }

    }); });
```

Comment: Thank you, since I was using this lib without any problem until nested search I didnt thnik implemeting my own. Now I have to :-)

Comment: Sometimes making your own solution is the way to go, we often hit walls when working with third party libraries so having the confidence to build around it is a great asset. 

Best of luck!